# SUM of values if condition is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to do a SUM of values if the name of the task is the same.

Please find an example below.

**Sheet1**

```
       A       |                  B   
1 |   Tasks    |   Result
2 |  Task 1    |  =SUMIF(Sheet2!D2:D7;A2;Sheet2!A2:A7)
3 |  Task 2    |  =SUMIF(Sheet2!D2:D7;A3;Sheet2!A2:A7)
4 |  Task 3    |  =SUMIF(Sheet2!D2:D7;A4;Sheet2!A2:A7)
```

**Sheet2**

```
      A      |     B     |    C     |     D
1 | Tasks    |   City    |   Age    |   Value 
2 | Task 1   |           |          |    10 
3 | Task 1   |           |          |    12
4 | Task 2   |           |          |    20
5 | Task 2   |           |          |    8 
6 | Task 2   |           |          |    2
7 | Task 3   |           |          |    45
```

For task 1, expected result is 22.
For task 2, expected result is 30.
For task 3, expected result is 45.

However, I'm getting 0.

Can you please explain me what is wrong in the formula ?

Thanks

Comment: sumif takes as a 1st param the range to check the condition and the last param is the range to sum. You've got them the other way around.

Comment: You can resume your data with Pivot Tables too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!D:D)
```

If you use specific range then use absolute position so that it do not chnages when you drag and down. Use-

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$7)
```

Good explanation here on [exceljet.](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function)

Answer (score 0):

Rather using relative references, you need to use absolute references. In simple words just use a $ sign to freeze rows in your formulae to prevent them shifting down when formula is down filled / copy pasted.

Here is an example:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!D$2:D$7;A2;Sheet2!A$2:A$7)
```

Same way you can prevent columns to shift if you use $ sign before column references in formulae.

Keyboard short cut to apply $ sign in a formula is F4 key. You select the range in formulae and press F4 key from your keyboard.

1st F4 key press: both rows and column would get frozen
2nd F4 key press: would freeze only row
3rd F4 key press: would remove row freeze and apply freeze to column
4th F4 key press: would remove all freeze and make the range relative